# Ubuntu Studio 17.04 - apt doesn't see the latest version of qbittorrent

Tags: apt, ppa, 16.10, repository, 17.04

I want to install latest version of qBittorrent (3.3.12) onto my Ubuntu Studio (17.04), but it only sees the old version (3.3.7). I've added the qBittorrent Stable PPA ([this one](https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable)), but it seems like my system doesn't see it.

The output of `apt-cache policy qbittorrent` is:

```
qbittorrent:
  Installed: 3.3.7-2
  Candidate: 3.3.7-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.7-2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The same thing happened when I was at Ubuntu Studio 16.10.

Can somebody help me with it?

Output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
google-chrome.list                      kxstudio-debian.gcc5.list  kxstudio-free.list                                me-davidsansome-ubuntu-clementine-dev-zesty.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                 kxstudio-debian.list       kxstudio-non-free.gcc5.list                       qbittorrent-team-ubuntu-qbittorrent-stable-zesty.list
jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-zesty.list       kxstudio-debian.new.list   kxstudio-non-free.list                            qbittorrent-team-ubuntu-qbittorrent-stable-zesty.list.save
jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-zesty.list.save  kxstudio-free.gcc5.list    me-davidsansome-ubuntu-clementine-dev-zesty.list  webupd8team-ubuntu-java-zesty.list
```

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qbittorrent-team-ubuntu-qbittorrent-stable-zesty.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu zesty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu zesty main
```

`grep -iE 'package|version' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa*qbitt*amd*`:

```
Package: libtorrent-rasterbar-dev
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: libtorrent-rasterbar-dbg
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: libtorrent-rasterbar-doc
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: python-libtorrent
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: python-libtorrent-dbg
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: python3-libtorrent
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: python3-libtorrent-dbg
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
Package: libtorrent-rasterbar8
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~zesty1
```

Comment: Have you update your lists after adding `ppa`? `sudo apt update`, was it successful?

Comment: I updated it a few times, the output didn't show any errors

Comment: What is the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` add it to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina updated the question

Comment: What is the output of this command `grep -iE 'package|version' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa*qbitt*amd*`?

Comment: @Ravexina added it to question

Comment: I  added an answer which describes whats happening here. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your outputs, and checking the `PPA`, what I can see is that something is wrong with `zesty PPA`'s `Packages` file; and after a little bit more research we will find out that there is no binary package for `zesty` at all.

I'm running `xenial`, I added the `PPA` and it's key, after updating my lists, the output of bellow command:

```
grep -iE 'package|version' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa*qbitt*amd*
```

Is:

```
...
Package: libtorrent-rasterbar-doc
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~xenial1
Package: qbittorrent
Version: 3.3.12-0ppa1~xenial
Package: python-libtorrent
Version: 1.0.11+git20172002.ecd20f15cb-1ppa1~xenial1
...
```

Which we can see that `qbittorrent` is there, so if I run `apt list -a qbittorrent`, I will get both Ubuntu and `PPA` packages available for install:

```
qbittorrent/xenial 3.3.12-0ppa1~xenial amd64
qbittorrent/xenial 3.3.1-1 amd64
```

If you [download](http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz) the packages list for `xenial` and checking it after extracting, you can see that it's contains `qbittorent`, however the Packages file for `zesty` does not contains `qbittorrent`: [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz)

And after all if you check the [pool](http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qbittorrent/) of this `PPA` you will see that there is no specific `deb` file for `zesty`.

At the end by checking [packages details](https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable/+packages) of PPA we can see the build process of zesty has been failed, so wait a little bit for a successful build.

Comment: OP could use the Xenial PPA if there is only one program and it doesn't lead to dependencies errors. :)

Comment: Actually the build has failed for zesty https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable/+packages. check there. I suggest including the link into your answer. There are two options for OP, wait until developers try another build or build themselves. Another option maybe using older debs from xenial

Comment: I tried to install Xenial version, but it depends on non-installable packages, so I'll wait for Zesty version to be fixed then. Thanks for the detailed answer ;)